# How to create multiple dropdown of all my model

Tags: django, algorithm, alphanumeric

how to create an alphanumeric that picks first initial letter of model name and generate for every user that signup

```
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

i want to create something like this

```
firstname = Seung
lastname = Jo
this will be the alphanumeric generated = SJ000001
```

Answer (score -1):

you can only use javascript library to do the autogeneration of alphanumeric

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).